# cannot starting start-dfs.sh in hadoop environment hadoop-env.sh problem?

Tags: hadoop

i try to start start-dfs.sh in hadoop environment that i just trying to create and i got this message, i don't know what this mean.. can anyone help me please,

> /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 300: /usr/local/hadoop/logs: Is a directory
>   /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 301: Java: command not found
>   Starting namenodes on [master]
>   ERROR: Both HADOOP_WORKERS and HADOOP_WORKER_NAMES were defined. Aborting.
>   Starting datanodes
>   WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR has been replaced by HADOOP_SECURE_LOG_DIR. Using value of HADOOP_S        ECURE_DN_LOG_DIR.
>   localhost: ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
>   Starting secondary namenodes [ip-172-31-93-240]
>   ERROR: Both HADOOP_WORKERS and HADOOP_WORKER_NAMES were defined. Aborting.

Answer (score 0):

comment or remove this line in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh (or maybe you defined this env variable on other files like bashrc):

`export HADOOP_WORKERS="${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/workers"`

then, unset HADOOP_WORKERS environment variable:

```
$ HADOOP_WORKERS=''
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.